# Quadratic second-order differential equation involving tan x

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a way to exactly solve the following differential equation:

$$\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 = -\tan x \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} $$

Comment: The equation would be easier to read if you used [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The equation being
$$(x')^2+\tan(x) x''=0$$ make
$$\cos(x)=z \implies x=\cos ^{-1}(z)\implies x'=-\frac{z'}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\implies x''=\frac{\left(z^2-1\right) z''-(z')^2}{\left(1-z^2\right)^{3/2}}$$ as well as $\tan(x)=\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{z}$.

You should get something very simple.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite
$$ -(\cot x)x' = \frac{x''}{x'} $$

Integrate both sides
$$ \ln(x') = -\ln(\sin x) + C $$

$$ \implies x' = \frac{A}{\sin x} $$

Separate and integrate again

$$ (\sin x)x' = A $$

$$ \cos x = B-At $$

Final solution

$$ x(t) = \arccos(B-At) $$